# How to change the alert box size?

Tags: php, jquery, html

How to change the alert box size?
I use the following coding.

In Firefox the alert box resize automatically but it not change in chrome?
Kindly give a solution.

```
window.alert("You answered all questions. Press OK to continue.");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alert box not responsive in chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22292387/alert-box-not-responsive-in-chrome)

Comment: It is not possible,The size depends on the browser

Answer (score 1):

#### You **can't** change the size/formatting/title (default settings) of the Javascript Alert Box. Instead you should check out [`JQuery Alert Box`](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

The [`Resizable JQuery Alert Box`](https://jqueryui.com/resizable/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Resizable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #resizable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
  #resizable h3 { text-align: center; margin: 0; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#resizable" ).resizable();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resizable</h3>
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify: When you use window.alert() you are using resources of your browser, not of your web page. It's the browser then who is responsible for creating the alert box, and thus you cannot influence its properties (like size etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I placed a single space in a new line at the end of my string which increased the length to a standard Windows message box.

```
Alert ("Hello World\n ");
```